# How to synchronize Tomboy notes

Tags: ubuntu-one, tomboy

Since Ubuntu One Tomboy sync is shutting down, what service I could use to synchronize my Tomboy notes between my Android, Windows, and Ubuntu boxes?  Without proper syncing, I have no incentive to keep using it.

Answer (score 7):

You can set up [Rainy](https://github.com/Dynalon/Rainy/) to run on your Ubuntu or Windows machine, and use it as the sync server in your Tomboy and Tomdroid clients. There is more information on Rainy and how to set it up at that link.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer to use Everpad (linux version of Evernote) as it offers greater functionality:

- Cross platform syncing & editing (unless I'm mistaken, Tomdroid still doesn't offer editing)
- Great Unity integration
- Notes, notebooks, tags, file attachment support
- Massive extensibility through Chrome/Firefox extensions

[Have a look at Evernote's official site](http://evernote.com/?noredirect) or [take a look at the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote)

To install Everpad in Ubuntu (12.04 and later*):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad
```

You do have to sign up to the service to use it, but it's **free** (which a paid version available too).

Log out and in again to get the lens to work.

If you use Gnome Shell, there's support available on the git page (see link below).

*Different sources say different things: [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/everpad-integrates-evernote-with-ubuntu.html) say that 11.10 onwards is supported, but the [official Everpad git repository](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad) says 12.04 onwards.

Comment: Tomdroid has suppor for editing since version 0.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think dropbox is a best choice. It's support android,windows,ubuntu etc. Just download here : https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx  , and install. Launch and set ur folder to sync. Normally folder name dropbox in your home directory will sync. Open Tomboy >edit >preferences >Syncronization  and set the folder to folder dropbox so everytime u save note from tomboy it will automatically sync to dropbox.

Note: im not a marketing of dropbox :D ...

Comment: Won't work for the android, you can't do it like that. What he is looking for is a tomboy note sync compatible server/service somewhere.

Comment: wow i guess i got downvote for answer this question :(( .unfair ;/

Comment: what? there is dropbox for android. Of course u can. I will show the pic .

Comment: Here's a tip as well you might want to add to your answer! https://plus.google.com/109365858706205035322/posts/JWcbLcsKek9

Comment: You can't sync the directory structure that tomdroid needs for that to work. Even if you could, you would need to open the dropbox app, sync, open tomdroid and *then* it might work, but it probably wouldn't.

Comment: SO this : http://lifehacker.com/5302854/synchronize-tomboy-notes-with-dropbox False? and this? http://www.starryhope.com/synchronize-tomboy-notes-with-dropbox/ and this http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/sync-tomboy-notes-computers-operating-systems/ and this ? http://matthewpoer.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/sync-tomboy-notes-using-dropbox/

Comment: Those links work fine for the Ubuntu <>Windows part, but **it won't work** for the Android part. The android port of tomboy (called tomdroid) didn't like that when I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started using btsync. It is working quite well! The desktop version requires some configuration of permissions. There is also Android apps: btsync and tomdroid.

I am quite excited that this has worked for me, and relatively simple to setup, no server required. In the past I have tried a lot of things. I still use Lucid on one of my machines so U1 has been broken a long time for me. Also the security is built into the btsync system so you don't need to worry about securing the server.

So for so good, but I only started doing this yesterday so I can't vouch for this working longer term yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use [grauphel](http://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php?action=content&content=166654) on your [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/) server to sync tomboy notes between Tomboy, Tomdroid and Conboy.

Comment: Grauphel appears to be promising.  I have installed ownCloud.  It works.  I downloaded the grauphel-0.4.0.tar.bz2 package and extracted it into the owncloud directory as a subdirectory.  The documents doesn't way where to put it.  The ownCloud server works as a cloud server, but I can't figure out how to actually sync tomboy and tomdroid.  If you can answer some steps to your answer it would be great!  Of provide a link where the actually steps are.  I read the readme files and the owncloud manual and can't find this.

Comment: You can install grauphel directly via the apps menu in owncloud. No need to manually download it. There is a screencast on tomdroid setup on my blog; http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/grauphel.htm

Comment: Thanks!  I had been on that screen.  When I follow the steps on that screen I don't see Tomboy on that screen.  I only see Files, Activity, Documents, Pictures, Calenda, and Contacts.  I also see a "+" Apps, which I clicked on.  I'm still with that.  I can't find Tomboy anywhere yet.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple and obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: For anyone having problems making the Tomboy/Tomdroid app appear in the owncloud apps, the extracted grauphel has to be installed in the apps directory of the owncloud directory found at the root of the appache installation.  Details are described at: http://askubuntu.com/a/566580/29012 We are extremely fortunate for cweiske's programming skills and contribute to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Owncloud server that works well for syncing tomboy notes and files remain under my control on my server. Some web hosting companies will host Owncloud for you and you will get many more features than available through dropbox. Owncloud has its own webdav server so that any application with webdav capabilities will be able to access the files. This uses all open source solutions.

1. Obtain Owncloud server access.
2. Install Owncloud client to access the server.
3. Create a folder within your owncloud folder to hold the tomboy *.note files.
4. The remaining steps involve moving your tomboy notes to your owncloud folder. I explained this step in more detail here [How do I specify the location Tomboy is to use to store the notes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67984/how-do-i-specify-the-location-tomboy-is-to-use-to-store-the-notes/584736#584736)