# How to add grauphel to the owncloud server

Tags: owncloud-server

Can someone tell me how to add "grauphel" to the owncloud server?

I have (easily) installed and setup the owncloud server and desktop client by using the repository.  Logging into it and actually using it is just as seamless as drop box.

It has options of adding other features such as grauphel.  I followed the link and downloaded the the grauphel package ([grauphel download and support page](https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/grauphel+-+Tomboy+sync+server?content=166654)), but there isn't many reference anywhere with the downloaded package of where to put it once downloaded so that it becomes integrated with owncloud.

The tar download comes with a readme file but it doesn't reference anywhere what to do with the extracted files.

Can someone help with how to perform this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being without Tomboy sync for a year, I finally discovered this grauphel app for owncloud.  I worked with it for a week trying to get it running and finally got it running.  I found lots of documentation and references, but all of them fail short when it comes to the actual steps to get it up and running.

I'm sure many people met the same or similar problems.

I'm going to work on steps that should work very easily for everyone and update this answer in a couple of days.  However in the meantime, I was able to install the grauphel app into own cloud by:

(For Ubuntu:)

1. Look into your Apache configuration `/etc/apache2` for the owncloud
   conf file.  I found a new directory created called `conf-enabled`.
2. Here I found an alias for owncloud: `/var/www/owncloud/`
3. Copy the grauphel directory extracted from the tar download to the apps folder of that
   directory.  You'll then have `/var/www/owncloud/apps/grauphel`.
4. Restart apache2.  Log into the server.  Then you'll have a new app
   available called `tomboy`.

If I find an easier method (or if anyone knows of an easier method), I'll update these steps to make it easier.  At present this works!

More details can be found at: http://faq.apollo3.com/TomboySync.html
The details in the link will be updated as I easier and more seamless ways for the steps.

---

*I'm told there is a way to install apps for owncloud without manually downloading them, but I couldn't find it documented anywhere.  It most likely is.  I'll edit these steps for that if I find such a method.*